# Adjust the distance between one pair of blocks in block diagram

Tags: diagrams, block

[image]

I want to move only the second block near to the third block so that variables between first and second block are clearly seen.  Other parts of block diagram should be kept the same. I have attached the output as `.png` image and the code is below

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{babel}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2.2cm,>=latex']
%placing the blocks
\node[text width=5em] [block] (node1) {ZC sequence generation $u,v,N_{cs}$};
\node[text width=3em] [block, right of=node1] (node2) {point point point };
\node[text width=2em] [block, right of=node2] (node3) {taking inverse};
\node[text width=4em] [block, right of=node3] (node4) {up filter sam};
\node[text width=5em] [block, below of=node4] (node5) {Add PP};
\node[text width=4em] [block, left of=node5] (node6) {Shifty Res Blo};
\node [output, left of=node6] (output) {};
%\node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=above,left of=node6] (node7) {Tx}; 
%connecting the blocks
\draw (0.98,0)--(1,0)[draw,->] (node1) -- node {$z_{u,v}(n)$} (node2);
\draw[-> ] (node2) -- (node3);
\draw[-> ] (node3) -- (node4);
\draw[-> ] (node4) -- (node5);
\draw[-> ] (node5) -- (node6);
\draw[-> ] (node6) -- node [name=Tx] {Tx}(output);  
%\draw[-> ] (node6) -- (node7);
\end{tikzpicture}\caption{\label{transmitter_block_diagram}transmission}
\end{figure}
\end{document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3):

Placing nodes relative to one another is better done with the help of `positioning` library. Add `\usetikzlibrary{positioning}` and change all `of =` to `= of`. Then adjust the node distance (which I kept as 1.3cm).

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shadows,positioning}


\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]%[H]
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, rectangle, minimum height=3em, minimum width=3em]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1.3cm,>=latex']
%placing the blocks
\node[text width=5em,block] (node1) {ZC sequence generation $u,v,N_{cs}$};
\node[text width=3em,block, right = of node1] (node2) {point point point };
\node[text width=2em,block, right = of node2] (node3) {taking inverse};
\node[text width=4em,block, right = of node3] (node4) {up filter sam};
\node[text width=5em,block, below = of node4] (node5) {Add PP};
\node[text width=4em,block, left = of node5] (node6) {Shifty Res Blo};
\node [output, left = of node6] (output) {};
%\node[dspnodeopen,dsp/label=above,left of=node6] (node7) {Tx};
%connecting the blocks
\draw (0.98,0)--(1,0)[draw,->] (node1) -- node {$z_{u,v}(n)$} (node2);
\draw[-> ] (node2) -- (node3);
\draw[-> ] (node3) -- (node4);
\draw[-> ] (node4) -- (node5);
\draw[-> ] (node5) -- (node6);
\draw[-> ] (node6) -- node [name=Tx] {Tx}(output);
%\draw[-> ] (node6) -- (node7);
\end{tikzpicture}%
\caption{\label{transmitter_block_diagram}transmission}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Remember that `positioning` library is more accurate in relative positioning.

Answer (score 1):

An another solution. With use of tikz library `chains`, without library `positioning`,  and node option `join` the code is:

```
\documentclass[english]{IEEEtran}
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,chains}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    > = {Latex[]},
    auto, 
    start chain = going right,
    node distance=13mm,
    block/.style={shape=rectangle, draw,
                  inner sep=1mm, align=center,
                  minimum height=4em, text width=#1,
                  join=by ->, on chain}]
%placing the blocks
\node[block=5em] (n1) {ZC sequence generation $u,v,N_{cs}$};
\node[block=3em] (n2) {point point point };
\node[block=3em] (n3) {taking inverse};
\node[block=4em] (n4) {up filter sam};
\node[block=5em,below=of n4] (n5) {Add PP};
\node[block=4em,left =of n5] (n6) {Shifty Res Blo};
%
\path (n1) --  node {$z_{u,v}(n)$} (n2);
\draw[->] (n6) --  node {Tx} (n6 -| n2.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\caption{\label{transmitter_block_diagram}transmission}
\end{figure}
    \end{document}
```

[image]